# Convert and count upper case and lowercase characters

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to convert all uppercase characters to lowercase and all lowercase to uppercase from a file.

I also want to count the characters read and the number of characters converted to uppercase and characters converted to lowercase.

I am able to convert the characters but unable to figure out how to count them.

**Example;**

```
Hello World!
```

**Output;**

```
hELLO wORLD!
```

- Read 13 characters in total.
- 8 converted to uppercase.
- 2 converted to lowercase.

Here's my code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INPUT_FILE      "input.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE     "output.txt"

int main()
{
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "rt");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", INPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    // 2. Open another file
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "wt");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", OUTPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }
    int c;
    int ch;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(inputFile))) {
        ch = islower(c)? toupper(c) : tolower(c);
        fputc(ch, outputFile);
    }
    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(inputFile))) {
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            upper++;
        }


        else if (islower(c))
        {
            lower++;
        }
        fputc(upper, outputFile);
        fputc(lower, outputFile);
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yoda conditionals needed not, compilers improved they have. Not to mention that you got the second `if` statement wrong anyways, proving that Yoda conditionals are no match for the human capacity for error.

Comment: Second `if (NULL == inputFile)` --> `if (NULL == outputFile)`

Comment: I am getting hELLO wORLD output in the output file but not the count.

Comment: The first `while` loop reads the whole file. Therefore, the second `while` loop reads `EOF` and never runs. The solution is to count the upper and lower case letters in the first `while` loop, and delete the second `while` loop.

Comment: You never enter the second loop. Why not convert and count in the same loop?

Comment: @user3386109 That gives weird output - 6801 0041 0101 5201 0245 0103 2001 0352
0104 4101 054d 0106 4101 0720 0107 6802
0741 0208 5202 0945 020a 2002 0a6b 030a
5203 0b49 030c 5303 0d48 030e 4e03 0f41
0310

Comment: @ShayGold I removed 2nd loop and did this for first one - while (EOF != (c = fgetc(inputFile))) {
        ch = islower(c)? toupper(c) : tolower(c);
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            upper++;
        }
        else if (islower(c))
        {
            lower++;
        }
        fputc(ch, outputFile);
        fputc(upper, outputFile);
        fputc(lower, outputFile);
    }

Comment: Yes, that's because of the `fputc(upper...` and `fputc(lower...`. Normally I would expect that you're supposed to write the modified text to the output file, and write the status message to the terminal. To write the status message, you need to learn how `printf` works.

Comment: @user3386109 i can do that using printf but i need to print it to the output file.

Comment: Ok, then you can use `fprintf` to print it at the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you are using 2 loops to read input file.
Your second loop should [rewind](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rewind.htm) the file before to start re-reading the file.

You can count and convert with a single loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define INPUT_FILE      "input.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILE     "output.txt"

int main()
{
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(INPUT_FILE, "rt");
    if (NULL == inputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", INPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    // 2. Open another file
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(OUTPUT_FILE, "w");
    if (NULL == outputFile) {
        printf("ERROR: cannot open the file: %s\n", OUTPUT_FILE);
        return -1;
    }

    int ch;
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(inputFile)))
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            if (islower(ch))
            {
                ch = toupper(ch);
                upper++;

            }
            else
            {
                ch = tolower(ch);
                lower++;
            }

            count++;
        }

        fputc(ch, outputFile);
    }

    fprintf(outputFile, "\nTotal: %d\nToUpper: %d\nToLower: %d\n", count, upper, lower);

    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Take also note that you have to check if a read char is an alpha char before to convert the case, as the `isalpha` call inside the loop do.